# Flutter upi payment integration through url launcher

Tags: flutter, upi, url-launcher

How can I retrieve the payment response from UPI Apps in flutter app?

So far, I have used the URL launcher plugin to redirect to a UPI app with pre-filled payment details. Here's an example of how I achieved the redirection:

```
String url = 'bhim://pay?pa=xxx@okbizaxis&pn=ABC&tr=15330175804633937&tn=MangOO Transaction&am=1&cu=INR&mc=5411';

if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(url);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch the UPI app.';
}
```

**However, I want to receive the payment response back in my Flutter app from the UPI app. The response should include transaction status, ID, and other relevant information, which I can then use to handle the place order functionality in my app.**

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to accomplish this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/upi_pay this is a good package that can be used.

Comment: Thanks @KrishBhanushali, this package has lots of issues, and for ios, it is not working as expected. Always going on whatsapp and after payment not redirecting back to the app, so response is not coming. On android also, Gpay payment is failing even after using business upi id, On phone pe, if payment is failed, then still giving success in response.  That's why looking for another approach.